# storing json string in gae

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, servlets

My goal is to store `JSON` string in GAE. `JSON` comes from regular post request to servlet.

I tried:

**1. Save it to file `filename.json` that I created in project. It Didn't work because files can not be accessed. Got error 500:**

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500

in servlet `doPost` method:

```
File file = new File("/res/filename.json");

if (file.exists()){
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
  bw.write(line);
  bw.close();
}else {
  ...
}
```

**2. Save it as string in google cloud storage in "bucket"
same error code 500.**

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

String filename = "/gs/" + "path_to_bucket" + "/" + "filename.json";
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(filename);
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, false);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
String res = reader.readLine();

resp.getWriter().println("READ:" + res);
```

According to my goals I need help with :

1) Best practices, about how to store JSON string in GAE

2) What tools I need and how to implement strategy like, I do post request `.../save` URL and servlet stores my JSON. Then I request `.../load` URL and other servlet reads the stored JSON and respond, accordingly.

Any help is welcome. If all this is unclear still, please let me know, I will try to further improve the explanation.

Comment: First of all App Engine does not have a concept of standard File System, you cannot simply save a file somewhere. The `FileWriter` class and the related ones are forbidden inside the App Engine environment.
Also, the `AppEngineFile` class is long deprecated (it uses the old `Blobstore`) while now there is a library to interact with Google Cloud Storage. [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) you can see how to interact with Cloud Storage with the newest library.

Comment: I did all according to the tutorial. In my Servlet I realized doPost and doGet ( copy - paste from link ) and organizing imports. Now I entered to my site, fill up all fields  ( Bucket: example.appspot.com; File Name: filename.json ) and press upload content. nothing happens except fields bucket and filename from download from bucket section  automatically fill up, then I press "download content" and get Error: Not Found
The requested URL /gcs/example.appspot.com/filename? was not found on this server.

Comment: Please update your comment with your current code and stacktrace error (if available)

Comment: when I send post request from other app I got 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: .... 

when I press "download content" on my site I got 
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /gcs/vendingmachinestorage.appspot.com/test.json? was not found on this server.

you can check it here : http://vendingmachinestorage.appspot.com/

Comment: my Servlet looks exactly like here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/example/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/GcsExampleServlet.java  
and I am sending post and get requests from other app to this servlet, am I right ?